# Printing a multidimensional array (board game)

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

Im trying to print a board game called snake and ladders. I only managed to print the first simple column.

```
var multiArray=[[" ___","|   |", "|   |","|___|"],
                ["|   |","|   |", "|___|","|   |"],
               ["| E |", "|___|","|   |","|   |"],
               ["|___|","|   |","|   |","|___|"],
               ["|   |","|   |","|___|","|   |"],
                ["| P |","|___|","|   |","|   |"],
                ["|___|"]];


for(var i=0; i<multiArray.length;i++){
    for(var j=0; j<multiArray[i].length;j++){
        print(multiArray[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Execution:

```
 ___ 
|   |
|   |
|___|
|   |
|   |
|___|
|   |
| E |
|___|
|   |
|   |
|___|
|   |
|   |
|___|
|   |
|   |
|___|
|   |
| P |
|___|
|   |
|   |
|___|
```

How can i do it so that the same column gets printed 7 more times beside it to look like this:

```
 ___ ___
|   |   |
|   |   |
|___|___|
|   |   |
|   |   |
|___|___|
|   |   |
| E |   |
|___|___|
|   |   |
|   |   |
|___|___|
|   |   |
|   |   |
|___|___| 
|   |   |
|   |   |
|___|___|  
|   |   |
| P |   |
|___|___|
|   |   |
|   |   |
|___|___|
```

I tried using .concat but it just adds it to the bottom of the other column. .join and .push is also not working unless im not using it correctly.

Comment: Where are these strings displayed? If it's a browser, you could use html and CSS to define the column layout and add each column's text individually. If you're printing to a console, you have to print by rows.

Comment: im using a school website called codeboot.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I can think of is this

```
var multiArray =
[
    [" ____",   "|   |",    "|   |",    "|___|"],
    ["|   |",   "|   |",    "|___|",    "|   |"],
    ["| E |",   "|___|",    "|   |",    "|   |"],
    ["|___|",   "|   |",    "|   |",    "|___|"],
    ["|   |",   "|   |",    "|___|",    "|   |"],
    ["| P |",   "|___|",    "|   |",    "|   |"],
    ["|___|"]
];

for (var i = 0; i < multiArray.length; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < multiArray[i].length; j++){
        // storing the second column. first col = second col
        var secondColumn    = multiArray[i][j];
        // checking if the column has E or P in it
        if (secondColumn.match(/(E|P)/)) {
            // if it does, change the column to empty one
            secondColumn = "|   |";
        }
        // print the same column twice (without E or P)
        console.log(multiArray[i][j] + secondColumn);
    }
}
```

Since you want to print the same column twice but without the letter E or P, a simple regexp will solve the problem.

If you want to use this in a html page, not in console or 'codeboot.org', you will have problems with your columns. You can't use multiple spaces in a string. HTML page will parse it as a single space. You need to change your spaces with `&nbsp;`. `&nbsp;` means a single space. You can use that multiple times.

You can see the space problem [here: fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WSEcF/).

**EDIT:** You said you want to print it 7 times. The code below will do.

```
for (var i = 0; i < multiArray.length; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < multiArray[i].length; j++){
        var col = multiArray[i][j];
        if (col.match(/(E|P)/)) {
            col = "|   |";
        }
        console.log(multiArray[i][j] + col + col + col + col + col + col);
    }
}
```

I don't know what E or P stands for, so the rest of the columns are empty.

**EDIT2:**

If you want to add to or remove from the columns with the current code, that's gonna be troubling. Addressing to the desired column would be hard since the columns are not organized. I give you an alternative way.

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

```
var container = document.getElementById("container");
var rows = 7;
var cols = 8;

for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    container.innerHTML += '<div class="row"></div>';
    var curRow = container.getElementsByClassName("row")[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++){
        curRow.innerHTML += '<div class="col"></div>';
    }
}

function addPlayer(p ,r, c) {
    var row = container.getElementsByClassName("row")[r-1];
    var col = row.getElementsByClassName("col")[c-1];
    col.innerHTML = p;
}

function clearColumn(r, c) {
    var row = container.getElementsByClassName("row")[r-1];
    var col = row.getElementsByClassName("col")[c-1];
    col.innerHTML = "";
}

// try passing player name, row number and column number
// in the given order
addPlayer("E", 3, 4);
addPlayer("P", 5, 2);

// you can also clear a specified column
// enter row number and column number
// clearColumn(5,2);
```

You should create your own html page and work with HTML/CSS if you want to improve this. An online interpreter won't help much.

You can see the live demo [here: fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p2DL4/).

Comment: yes i would like to print the next 7 columns but there are different letters in them. lets say that Player 1 is on the first row column 3. then i would have to xenter p1 at that location.

Comment: @user3268216 Updated my answer. It should solve your problems.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it would be easier to print out the board by row rather than by column.  This way, you're using the problem of only being able to print below as the solution by intentionally printing each row under the previous row.

This would require a redefinition of your multiarray, but the first row could look something like this:

```
var upperBound  = '  _______________________'
var side        =  '|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | '
var bottomBound =  '|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|__|'
console.log(upperBound, '\n', side, '\n', bottomBound)
```

Then you could repeat that 7 more times (without the upperBound), and get your board!

```
console.log(upperBound, '\n', side, '\n', bottomBound)
for(var i = 0; i < 7; i++){
    console.log(side, '\n', bottomBound)
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: wouldnt everything be changed if i would to enter something into the boxes?as in the rows or columns will not fit

Comment: Well, sort of, but it would be the same in the case of printing columns.  To enter something in the box, you could just remove one of the spaces.